# Getting WebRTC IceCandidates before createOffer or createAnswer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, video, webrtc

During establishing the video call ice candidates gathereing is started after the call to createOffer or createAnswer. I'd like to get all local ice candidates for the local peer before I call createOffer or createAnswer. This way I'll have all of them set in sdp description and there will be no need to send them separately to remote peer as they will go all together in sdp. Is it possible?

UPD:
All I want is to gather Ice candidates and keep them. After I want to create offers and asnwers but without of waiting for gathering of candidates will fininsh. Also How to add Ice candidates to description manually? And Is it possible to disabale Ice candidates gathering without recreating RTCPeerConnection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Candidate gathering only starts when you call setLocalDescription.

If you want an SDP with all the candidates, wait for the onicecandidate event without a candidate and inspect the peerconnection's localDescription.sdp which contains all candidates gathered so far.

Comment: I setLocalDescription after the call to createAnswer or createOffer. This is the place where I can get the actual description from callback https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection#createOffer Is it ok to call setLocalDescription with null, so the Ice gathering will start? (also I updated the question)

Comment: no, calling SLD with null is not legal. And you are not allowed to add candidates manually. If you're trying to decrease latency you really want to use trickle ice -- see https://webrtchacks.com/trickle-ice/

Comment: Thanks so much for this saved me!

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the delay by setting icecandidatepoolsize - then the browser will try and pre-gather candidates before Offer/Answer.

see:
https://github.com/pipe/two/blob/master/index.html#L181

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onicecandidate

When onicecandidate event in callback is null, issue that the peer connection has gather ice candidate complete. So at that time Create offer to other peer connection and the Offer's SDP info will contain 'a=candidate' attribute.

Reference: https://aggresss.github.io/webrtc-samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1-mod/